# how is the ".shift()" method being used in this CodeSchool example?

Tags: javascript, function

I've been following along with the CodeSchool Javascript tutorial and understanding everything until I was stumped by this problem:

> In a variable called applyAndEmpty, build and store a function that
>   takes in an input number and a Queue of functions as parameters. Using
>   a for loop, apply the Queue’s functions in order to the input number,
>   where the results of each function become the next function’s input.
>   Additionally, the Queue should be empty after the function is called.

It provided this solution:

```
var puzzlers = [
    function (a) { return 8*a - 10; },
    function (a) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); },
    function (a) { return a * a + 4; },
    function (a) { return a % 5; }
];
var start = 2;

var applyAndEmpty = function(input, queue) {
  var length = queue.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    input = queue.shift()(input);
  }
  return input;
};
alert(applyAndEmpty(start, puzzlers));
```

I've commented every line of the solution but I have no idea why the line "queue.shift()(input);" has the shift method use a second set of parenthesis. I looked at the method signature on the Mozilla Developer Network and they don't have an example of this usage. I find this syntax very weird. Can someone explain why this works and what is going on here conceptually?

Answer (score 2):

The `shift` method returns an item from the array, so the value of `queue.shift()` is a function. The `(input)` after it is calling the function with `input` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I figured this out not more than a few minutes after I wrote it.